# Faster way to find elements in list/array

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I'm working on a finite element program where my input are a list of nodes `(ListNodes double[node_index, x, y, z]` where `(x,y,z)` are the coordinate of node in Cartesian system), a list of elements `(ListElements double[element_index, node1_index, node2_index, etc])` and some data for each element `(double[element_index])`.

I have to constanly searching for data at some given zone in the finite element model, a zone is defined by some bound `[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax]`. In order to retrieve data for this zone, I first look for its nodes (searching nodes such that `(x,y,z)` are inside the bound) then look for its elements and finally retrieve the data for such elements.

Function 1: check if node is inside the zone

```cs
private static bool IsBounded(double[] node, double xmin, double ymin, double zmin, double xmax, double ymax, double zmax)
{
    return ((node[1] >= xmin) && (node[1] <= xmax) && (node[2] >= ymin) && (node[2] <= ymax) && (node[3] >= zmin) && (node[3] <= zmax));
}
```

Function 2: check all nodes to find nodes inside the zone and Add them to zoneNodes

```cs
ListPoint.Where(node => IsBounded(node, xmin, ymin, zmin, xmax, ymax, zmax)).ToList().ForEach(node => zoneNodes.Add(Convert.ToInt32(node[0])));
```

Function 3: find elements inside the zone

```cs
// Loop over all elements
for (int j = 0; j < ListElement.Count; j++)
{
    int status = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < ElementList[j].Count; i++)
    {
        // For each element, check how many nodes are inside the zone
        if (zoneNodes.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(ListElement[j][i])))
        {
            status++;
        }
    }

    // If all the nodes of this element are inside the zone then the element is inside the zone
    if (status == ListElement[j].Count - 1)
    {
        zoneElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(ElementList[j][0]));
    }
}
```

Function 4: for each element inside the zone, we then can retrieve the data

This process is however terribly slow. Is there any way to improve this process for faster performance?

Thanks,

Comment: Please, have a look at **R-tree** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, but why Rtree? If I use Rtree, I have to reindex all my elements number?

Comment: R-Tree is a typical *data structure* we use for spatial data. As far as I can see from the code you've provided you, technically, don't use elements numbers: instead, you are solving "if the element is in the zone" problem - the very task R-Tree has been designed for

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this code is what you want.

Please check out.

A main thing to reduce time for calculating is using Dictionary.

Time complexity of Dictionary is normally O(1).

```
public class Sample
{
    // add data to that variables.
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, Point> pointPerElement = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, Point>();
    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, Cube> cubePerElement = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<double, Cube>();
    System.Collections.Generic.List<double> elements = new System.Collections.Generic.List<double>();

    private void Calculate()
    {
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            if (pointPerElement.ContainsKey(element) == false || cubePerElement.ContainsKey(element) == false)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var point = pointPerElement[element];
            var cube = cubePerElement[element];
            if (cube.IsBouded(point))
            {
                // add point or cube or element to list.
            }
        }
    }
}

private struct Point
{
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;

    public Point(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
    }

    public static Point GetVector(Point from, Point to)
    {
        return new Point(to.x - from.x, to.y - from.y, to.z - from.z);
    }
}

private struct Range
{
    public double min;
    public double max;

    public double length;
    public double center;

    public Range(double min, double max)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(min < max);
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.length = max - min;
        this.center = length * 0.5;
    }
}

private struct Cube
{
    public Range xRange;
    public Range yRange;
    public Range zRange;

    private Point center;

    public Cube(Range xRange, Range yRange, Range zRange)
    {
        this.xRange = xRange;
        this.yRange = yRange;
        this.zRange = zRange;

        this.center = new Point(xRange.center, yRange.center, zRange.center);
    }

    public bool IsBouded(Point point)
    {
        var v = Point.GetVector(point, this.center);
        var doubledV = new Point(v.x * 2, v.y * 2, v.z * 2);
        return doubledV.x <= this.xRange.length
            && doubledV.y <= this.yRange.length
            && doubledV.z <= this.yRange.length;
    }
}
```